# robot_localization/ekf_localization when working with namespaces

Tags: ros, ekf, namespaces, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on Clearpath's Jackal now and trying to spawn it on a Gazebo world with another robot. For that (as far as I understand) I need to use namespaces (one for each robot).
I have taken the original launch files provided by Clearpath and tried to modify them. I have noticed that in jackal_control/control.launch they launch the ekf_localization node. When I comment out this line - everything works, but when it's not commented, things don't work.

The bottom line of my question: what do I need to do in order to work with the ekf_localization node in a namespace? I tried to simply wrap it in a namespace and it didn't work. I tried to define a tf_prefix and it also didn't help.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228866/robot_localization/ekf_localization-when-working-with-namespaces/) by [Omer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25199/omer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-03-13**:
Perhaps you could give us more detail? When you say it "doesn't work," what do you mean?

**Comment by [Omer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25199/omer/) on 2016-03-14**:
Either one of two things happens: my Gazebo world doesn't open or it does open and gets hung a few seconds later (when I'm trying to change the field of view)

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-03-20**:
I'm sorry, do you mean to say that you're not having trouble with `robot_localization`, but with Gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Omer,

What I understand from your question is that you want to launch two instances of robot_localization for two different robots by launching then under different name_spaces.

To launch the robot_localization node under a name_space you can use  [tag](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group) or you can pass argument __ns (args="__ns=name_space"). After this your launch file would include:

```
<node ns="bot1" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization">
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find jackal_control)/config/robot_localization_bot1.yaml" />
</node>   
<node ns="bot2" pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization">
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find jackal_control)/config/robot_localization_bot2.yaml" />
</node>
```

after this you would need to modify your yaml files accordingly,

```
frequency: 50
odom0: /jackal_velocity_controller/odom   #odom source for respective robot
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
false, false, false,
true, true, true,
false, false, true,
false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
imu0: /imu/data #imu source for respective bot
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
true, true, true,
false, false, false,
true, true, true,
false, false, false]
imu0_differential: false
odom_frame: odom  # fixed frame for robot (this can be same for both)
base_link_frame: base_link #fixed frame for robot (this should be diffenret for both)
world_frame: odom #again same is fine
```

make sure that you publish static transforms between IMU frame and baselink for both the robots

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Omer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25199/omer/) on 2016-03-12**:
Thanks Sudeep. I have tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work. By the way, what changes do I need in the yaml file?

**Comment by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) on 2016-03-13**:
As mentioned in Answer, major changes would be odom0, imu0, odom_frame, base_link_frame, world_frame @Omer